# Change Focus after button press

Tags: javascript, focus, keypress

I have a simple button that calls a routine onClick.
I use

```
document.getElementById('Start').disabled=true;
```

to disable the button so it can not be pressed again. On most things there is no problem after that. In one instance I need to detect key presses, or rather key releases  once the button is klicked.I use

```
document.onkeyup=WichKeyPressed;
```

to detect the key press. This works fine if I do not disable the button, but it does not work if I disable the button.

It must be a focus problem. If I click the mouse on a blank area on the screen, the key press is detected with or without disabling the button. I have tried changing the focus to several other elements, but so far no go. I have even given the BODY an id and tried to change focus to it, but the results remain the same.

I would appreciate any ideas on the subject.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling the button, you could just add a CSS class and set a flag preventing the action from happening again when the button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks, I have done something similar already, so the code is working, but it annoys me that I am missing something. The problem should not exist and there has to be a reason for it. By the way , the problem only occurs in Firefox 3 not in IE 8. Which is actually annoys me even more. In IE you can actually see the button is activated during each keypress, but at least it obeys the disable flag, and registers the keypresses. Firefox does neither.

Comment: I have just discovered the solution. I assume it should have been obvious even though I have not seen it stated explicitly any where. Apparently my focus change failed because it is not enough to redirect the browser's attention, you also need to make the browser lose interest in the previous target with .blur. So blur and focus has to be used in pairs at least in this case.

Comment: @JdT: You should post that as an answer. :)